# Higher version of guest OS Virtualbox on Lower version of native Host OS.

Tags: virtualbox

Is it possible to create virtual machine using virtual box running Windows 10 and the actual physical machine OS running older version i.e., windows7

Answer (score 1):

As long as the version of **Virtualbox** supports the host version, then you can pretty much create a virtual machine with any OS you want. You can install your **Virtualbox** on Linux and have a Windows 10 virtual machine, or install it on top of Windows 7 and have a Windows 10 virtual machine. There are no limitations to the operating system you can virtualize, as long as it is supported.

[Here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes) is a list with supported Guest OSes.

Comment: Thanks, for answering this. My question was to ascertain myself that I can install docker on Windows 10 VM spin using virtual box(min reqmnt for installing docker on Windows) as my lappy current has Windows 7 OS and don't wants to upgrade OS for now.

Comment: @AnkitVerma yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, *technically speaking*, you can. There's no borders. But as you will start using the guest add on - be prepared for a trouble